# INNER JOIN Results from Select Statement using Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Can you use Doctrine QueryBuilder to `INNER JOIN` a temporary table from a full `SELECT` statement that includes a `GROUP BY`?

The ultimate goal is to select the best version of a record. I have a viewVersion table that has multiple versions with the same viewId value but different timeMod. I want to find the version with the latest timeMod (and do a lot of other complex joins and filters on the query).

Initially people assume you can do a `GROUP BY viewId` and then `ORDER BY timeMod`, but ORDER BY has no effect on GROUP BY, and MySQL will return random results. There are a ton of answers out there (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770936/3334390)) that explain the problem with using GROUP and offer a solution, but I am having trouble interpreting the Doctrine docs to find a way to implement the SQL with Doctrine QueryBuilder (if it's even possible). Why don't I just use DQL? I may have to, but I have a lot of dynamic filters and joins that are much easier to do with QueryBuilder, so I wanted to see if that's possible.

### Sample MySQL to Reproduce in Doctrine QueryBuilder

```
SELECT vv.* 
FROM view_version vv
#inner join only returns where the result sets overlap, i.e. one record
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(timeMod) maxTimeMod, viewId
    FROM view_version
    GROUP BY viewId
) version ON version.viewId = vv.viewId AND vv.timeMod = version.maxTimeMod
#join other tables for filter, etc
INNER JOIN view v ON v.id = vv.viewId
INNER JOIN content_type c ON c.id = v.contentTypeId
WHERE vv.siteId=1
AND v.contentTypeId IN (2)
ORDER BY vv.title ASC;
```

### Theoretical Solution via Query Builder (not working)

I am thinking that the JOIN needs to inject a DQL statement, e.g.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$viewVersionRepo = $em->getRepository('GutensiteCmsBundle:View\ViewVersion');

$queryMax = $viewVersionRepo->createQueryBuilder()
    ->addSelect('MAX(timeMod) AS timeModMax')
    ->addSelect('viewId')
    ->groupBy('viewId');

$queryBuilder = $viewVersionRepo->createQueryBuilder('vv')
    // I tried putting the query in a parenthesis, to no avail
    ->join('('.$queryMax->getDQL().')', 'version', 'WITH', 'vv.viewId = version.viewId AND vv.timeMod = version.timeModMax')
    // Join other Entities
    ->join('e.view', 'view')
    ->addSelect('view')
    ->join('view.contentType', 'contentType')
    ->addSelect('contentType')
    // Perform random filters
    ->andWhere('vv.siteId = :siteId')->setParameter('siteId', 1)
    ->andWhere('view.contentTypeId IN(:contentTypeId)')->setParameter('contentTypeId', $contentTypeIds)
    ->addOrderBy('e.title', 'ASC');

$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();
```

My code (which may not match the above example perfectly) outputs:

```
SELECT e, view, contentType 
FROM Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\ViewVersion e 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(v.timeMod) AS timeModMax, v.viewId 
    FROM Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\ViewVersion v 
    GROUP BY v.viewId
) version WITH vv.viewId = version.viewId AND vv.timeMod = version.timeModMax 
INNER JOIN e.view view 
INNER JOIN view.contentType contentType 
WHERE e.siteId = :siteId 
AND view.contentTypeId IN (:contentTypeId) 
ORDER BY e.title ASC
```

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11925750/3334390) seems to indicate that it's possible in other contexts like `IN` statements, but when I try the above method in the JOIN, I get the error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 90 near '(SELECT MAX(v.timeMod)': Error: Class '(' is not defined.
```

Comment: @Javad Can you elaborate, because the query I included does in fact work exactly as I wrote it, with a SELECT inside the JOIN. And the answer you referenced actually says you can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12492267/3334390

Comment: From my research: QueryBuilder is just a way to build DQL, and DQL is an **entity query language**, not a *database query language*. So it's not designed to allow regular MySQL queries. I believe I will have to write this as a createNativeQuery() and use the resultSetMappingBuilder to bind everything... fun.

Comment: Apparently people are saying that it is **IMPOSSIBLE** to JOIN a subquery in DQL. That seems like a huge hole in Doctrine. I thought I could prepare the DQL then convert it to native SQL and just preg_replace and insert the subquery... but unfortunately, you can't convert DQL to native SQL, because it sends prepared statements to the database, not raw SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big thanks to @AdrienCarniero for his [alternative query structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/3334390) for sorting the highest version with a simple JOIN where the entity's timeMod is less than the joined table timeMod.

### Alternative Query

```
SELECT view_version.* 
FROM view_version
#inner join to get the best version
LEFT JOIN view_version AS best_version ON best_version.viewId = view_version.viewId AND best_version.timeMod > view_version.timeMod
#join other tables for filter, etc
INNER JOIN view ON view.id = view_version.viewId
INNER JOIN content_type ON content_type.id = view.contentTypeId
WHERE view_version.siteId=1
# LIMIT Best Version
AND best_version.timeMod IS NULL
AND view.contentTypeId IN (2)
ORDER BY view_version.title ASC;
```

### Using Doctrine QueryBuilder

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$viewVersionRepo = $em->getRepository('GutensiteCmsBundle:View\ViewVersion');

$queryBuilder = $viewVersionRepo->createQueryBuilder('vv')
    // Join Best Version
    ->leftJoin('GutensiteCmsBundle:View\ViewVersion', 'bestVersion', 'WITH', 'bestVersion.viewId = e.viewId AND bestVersion.timeMod > e.timeMod')
    // Join other Entities
    ->join('e.view', 'view')
    ->addSelect('view')
    ->join('view.contentType', 'contentType')
    ->addSelect('contentType')
    // Perform random filters
    ->andWhere('vv.siteId = :siteId')->setParameter('siteId', 1)
    // LIMIT Joined Best Version
    ->andWhere('bestVersion.timeMod IS NULL')
    ->andWhere('view.contentTypeId IN(:contentTypeId)')->setParameter('contentTypeId', $contentTypeIds)
    ->addOrderBy('e.title', 'ASC');

$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();
```

In terms of performance, it really depends on the dataset. [See this discussion for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group).

*TIP: The table should include indexes on both these values (viewId and timeMod) to speed up results. I don't know if it would also benefit from a single index on both fields.*

A native SQL query using the original JOIN method *may* be better in some cases, but compiling the query over an extended range of code that dynamically creates it, and getting the mappings correct is a pain. So this is at least an alternative solution that I hope helps others.

Comment: This is definitely the solutiob to my last two questions on SO. many thanks man