# Can Doctrine Join itself

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

As [described in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007090/inner-join-results-from-select-statement-using-doctrine-querybuilder), I have a `ViewVersion` entity that contains multiple versions for a given `View`. If I want to fetch a list of the "best" viewVersions based on which is the last modified, you can **not** do a `GROUP BY viewId` because you can't control the order these return (e.g. timeMod DESC). So you after days of searching I *believe* the best way to do this is through a simple INNER JOIN on itself that matches the highest timeMod.

This works really well in MySQL, but how in the world can you do this in Doctrine?

### Native MySQL Query

```
SELECT view_version.* 
FROM view_version
#inner join only returns where the result sets overlap, i.e. the one record with highest timeMod
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(timeMod) maxTimeMod, viewId
    FROM view_version
    GROUP BY viewId
) version ON version.viewId = view_version.viewId AND view_version.timeMod = version.maxTimeMod
#join other tables for filter, etc
INNER JOIN view ON view.id = view_version.viewId
INNER JOIN content_type ON content_type.id = view.contentTypeId
WHERE view_version.siteId=1
AND view.contentTypeId IN (2)
ORDER BY view_version.title ASC
```

### Question

How can you form a Doctrine query to join an entity TO ITSELF, using QueryBuilder or DQL (or if absolutely necessary Native).

Everytime I try, the `INNER JOIN` complains about the SELECT statement like so:

```
QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 72 near '(SELECT': Error: Class '(' is not defined
```

***NOTE***: this is different than my original question, in that this is focused specifically on joining an entity to itself.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the specifically stated question, you can easily join any entity to itself (even if it does not have a self-referential association), simply by joining to the entity shortcut name (instead of the associated field name like normal).

```
$viewVersionRepo = $em->getRepository('GutensiteCmsBundle:View\ViewVersion');   
$queryBuilder    = $viewVersionRepo->createQueryBuilder('e')   

    // JOIN ENTITY TO ITSELF - VIA BUNDLE SHORTCUT NAME
    ->join('GutensiteCmsBundle:View\ViewVersion', 'version', 'WITH', 'e.viewId = version.viewId')

    // JOIN OTHER ASSOCIATED ENTITIES - VIA FIELD NAME
    ->join('e.view', 'view')
    ->addSelect('view')
    ->join('view.contentType', 'contentType')
    ->addSelect('contentType')

    // PERFORM RANDOM FILTERS
    ->andWhere('e.siteId = :siteId')->setParameter('siteId', 1)
    ->addOrderBy('e.title', 'ASC');

$query      = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$results    = $query->getResult();
```

This however, is *NOT* accomplishing the same thing as the query in the question. It is NOT joining a temporary table from a select statement, which is what is needed in this case (and the other question referenced). There is no MAX column join here, because you can't GROUP a join. You can GROUP the main query, by a column from the JOINED table, but that doesn't let you perform a MAX on the ON/WITH portion of the JOIN.

But hopefully this answer is at least helpful to anyone else that wanted to know **how to join an entity to itself or any random entity**.