# Join a subquery with Doctrine DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

Using Doctrine in Symfony2, I need to recover each items and for each of them, the latest timestamp of their report.
So I would like to execute a query using DQL, which would be like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * from `item` i
LEFT JOIN `kit` k ON k.`id` = i.`kit_id`
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT e.`item_id`, MAX(e.`dateCreation`) 
    FROM `entete_rapport` e
    GROUP BY e.`item_id`) latest ON latest.`item_id` = i.`id`
```

I am not able to have the same with DQL. I guess I have to separate the subquery et the main one, with something like this:

```
$subSelect->select('e AS ItemId, MAX(e.dateCreation) AS latest')
                ->from('CATUParkBundle:EnteteRapport', 'e')
                ->groupBy('e.item');

$qb->select('i')
                ->from('CATUParkBundle:Item', 'i')
                ->leftJoin('i.kit', 'k')
                ->leftJoin('CATUParkBundle:EnteteRapport f', sprintf('(%s)', $subSelect->getDQL()), 'latest', 'f.id = latest.ItemId');
```

I am not able to make this query work, I really need you guys.
Thank you in advance, you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like subqueries in joins [do not work in dql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007090/inner-join-results-from-select-statement-using-doctrine-querybuilder#comment42611323_27007090). (I get error message: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 52 near '(SELECT e': Error: Class '(' is not defined.`)

You could run `$em->getConnection()->prepare($yourRawSql)->execute()->fetchAll()`, but this returns a raw result array (no objects). See [raw sql queries on knp-lab](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/raw-sql-queries)

Or do it in dql with HAVING instead of a subquery join:

```
$qb->select('i', 'i')
    ->addSelect('MAX(e.dateCreation)', 'date')
    ->from('CATUParkBundle:Item', 'i')
    ->leftJoin('i.kit', 'k')
    ->leftJoin('i.rapportOrWhatEver', 'f')
    ->groupBy('e.id');
```