# MAX value in MySQL without MAX function and Correlated Subqueries

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I want get max value in query MySQL **without MAX()** function because it's very slow. Ideally I want with `LEFT JOIN`.

> **References :**
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html
>
> [INNER JOIN Results from Select Statement using Doctrine QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007090/inner-join-results-from-select-statement-using-doctrine-querybuilder)

**My Query MySQL :**

```
SELECT
    fs.id AS subject,
    fpv.id AS post_version_id
FROM 
    forum_subject fs
    INNER JOIN
        forum_post_version fpv
        ON fpv.forum_subject_id = fs.id
WHERE
    fs.id IN (10817, 10818)
```

**Results :**

> **subject | post_version_id**
>
> 10817 | 528385
>
> 10817 | 528386
>
> 10818 | 528387
>
> 10818 | 528388

I want to return only one line : the maximum `post_version_id`.

Thank you for considering that my real case is much more complex :

- In my real case, this query is the continuation of other joins ;
- More line in each tables (> 50 000)

**EDIT** : Original query :

```
  SELECT 
    f13_.id 
  FROM 
    forum_subject_version f14_
    LEFT JOIN forum_subject_version f15_ ON (
      f15_.forum_category_id = f14_.forum_category_id 
      AND f14_.forum_subject_id = f15_.forum_subject_id 
      AND f14_.id < f15_.id
    ) 
    INNER JOIN forum_subject f16_ ON f14_.forum_subject_id = f16_.id 
    INNER JOIN forum_post_version f17_ ON (f17_.forum_subject_id = f16_.id) 
    LEFT JOIN forum_post_version f18_ ON (
      f18_.forum_subject_id = f16_.id 
      AND f17_.forum_post_id = f18_.forum_post_id 
      AND f17_.id < f18_.id
    ) 
    INNER JOIN forum_post f13_ ON f17_.forum_post_id = f13_.id 
  WHERE 
    f14_.forum_category_id IN (217, 218)
    AND f15_.id IS NULL 
    AND f18_.id IS NULL
```

- f14_ => 2400 lines
- f15_ => 480 lines ↘ (LEFT JOIN FILTER)
- f16_ => 480 lines =
- f17_ => 24000 lines ↗
- f18_ => 4800 lines ↘ (LEFT JOIN FILTER)
- f13_ => 4800 lines =
- *I want LEFT JOIN FILTER again for 2 lines*

Return 4800 lines (2400 in #217 `forum_category_id`, 2400 in #218 `forum_category_id`), I want 2 lines, one per forum category (1 in #217 `forum_category_id`, 1 in #218 `forum_category_id`).

I can't use ORDER + LIMIT and I don't want this : [MIN/MAX vs ORDER BY and LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit). MySQL recommand LEFT JOIN for filter but I can not do it in my situation **after f13_ alias**. :)

Comment: ORDER BY + LIMIT 1 ?

Comment: Thanks but I can't in my situation because this this query is the continuation of other joins (Forum > Forum Subject > Forum Post Version). In my real case, I want max post_version_id for each forum ; I have 8 forums = finally I want 8 lines

Comment: You should post the real code  ...  and not juts a part . ..the code provide is not enough

Comment: I edited my post, thanks :)

Comment: I edited my post again :)